# Find an analytic function defined on the upper half plane such that...

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two disjoint disks. Find an analytic function $f$ defined on the upper half plane such that $f$ takes every value in $D_1$ exactly once and every value of $D_2$ exactly twice.

This is a question in some qualifying exam of complex analysis and I don't know how to construct this mapping.

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can assume that $D_1$ lies in the lower half-plane, and $D_2$ in the upper half-plane. Does that suggest something?

Comment: I have no idea on it. Can you give me more hint? @DanielFischer  Thank you!

Comment: Can you find an analytic function on the upper half-plane that attains each point in the upper half-plane exactly twice, and each point in the lower half-plane exactly once?

Comment: $f(z)=z^3 .$ Thank you very much. @DanielFischer